# Get all text channels and change permissions in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I would like to be able to change the `send_messages` permission to off to be able to lock all channels, like "lockdown" command.

The command : `await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)`

Comment: Have you tried iterating through all the channels? Can you send the code you tried?

Comment: i've tried this : `await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role,send_messages=False)` and it works, but for only 1 channel.

Comment: Can you edit the code you have tried into the question? What do you have for the entire command so far?

Comment: It justs edit the permissions for the channel in which the command was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for channel in guild.channels:
       if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
           await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
```

Try this out :D

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Awesome @gqdThinky !